How to fix reading audio file with ExoPlayer?
I am new in Kotlin. I found interesting code of simple audio player on github
text
I tried to implement such variety of this into my project. And that is my code (I this part is broken):
@Composable
fun PlayerScreen(
    viewModel: PlayerViewModel,
    onBack: () -> Unit
) {
    val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(LocalContext.current).build()
    if (viewModel.currentUri != "".toUri()) {
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(viewModel.currentUri)
        player.addMediaItem(mediaItem)
        try {
            player.prepare()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("PlayerError", "Failed to prepare player", e)
        }

        val isPlaying = remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }

        val currentPosition = remember {
            mutableLongStateOf(0L)
        }

        val sliderPosition = remember {
            mutableLongStateOf(0L)
        }

        val totalDuration = remember {
            mutableLongStateOf(0L)
        }

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = player.currentPosition, key2 = player.isPlaying) {
            delay(1000)
            currentPosition.longValue = player.currentPosition
        }

        LaunchedEffect(currentPosition) {
            sliderPosition.longValue = currentPosition.longValue
        }

        LaunchedEffect(player.duration) {
            if (player.duration > 0) {
                totalDuration.longValue = player.duration
                System.out.println("GOOD")
            } else {
                System.out.println("SJFHLSFLJNBNSLKJNSFJNSBJNSKBJNKSJNO OIA U")
            }
        }

        Scaffold {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(
                    top = it.calculateTopPadding() + 16.dp,
                    start = 16.dp,
                    end = 16.dp,
                    bottom = it.calculateBottomPadding() + 16.dp,
                ),
            ) {
...

Here I am taking Uri from viewModel. Viewmodel file:
const val SONG =
    "https://spaces.im/files/download/cs10/music/f/000063053081071134189001020218243083005076226213207117015070/1716155189/56378474/0/662a3193125ba98834aa88ca51e6b78c/%2528Rington%2529_Panic_At_The_Disco_-_Halleluja-world76.spcs.bi.mp3"

@HiltViewModel
class PlayerViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    private val chapterRepository: ChapterRepository,
    private val bookRepository: BookRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    var currentUri by mutableStateOf("".toUri())

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            currentUri = SONG.toUri()
        }
    }
}

As in the example, the duration of music files return after play button, but my code does not do this. TrackBar component always has "00:00" on both sides.
I can't understand why
